# SQL query from two tables logical linked

Tags: sql

I try to write a SQL query which shall bring the following logic

```
IF ((ValueA FROM TableA.ColumnA > 1000 WHERE TableA.ColumnB = 'someString') 
    AND (ValueB FROM TableB.ColumnB = 'someOtherString'))
  THEN true 
  ELSE false
```

Any suggestions?

My actual attempt was:

```
SELECT knx.payload, piko.status 
FROM `KNXgroup` knx, `PIKO10data` piko 
WHERE 'knx.topic' = '6/4/204' 
ORDER BY 'knx.id' DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

which failed to work.

At least I managed to get the single values from both tables with

```
SELECT payload 
FROM `KNXgroup` 
WHERE `topic` = '6/4/204' 
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT status 
FROM `PIKO10data` 
ORDER BY `ID` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What is the relationship between TableA and TableB? Can you share sample data and desired results. I think it would help clarify.

Comment: Are you just looking to get single values back? Like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT payload FROM KNXgroup WHERE topic = '6/4/206' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) k, (SELECT status FROM PIKO10data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) p`?

Comment: @JNevill, thank you. The proposed query brings the requested values (payload and status) from both tables. Now just the logical evaluation "If payload > 1000 and status = 1 THEN true ELSE false" is the last challenge for me

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN k.payload > 1000 AND p.status = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END FROM (SELECT payload FROM KNXgroup WHERE topic = '6/4/206' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) k, (SELECT status FROM PIKO10data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) p` Total guess if that is the logic you are looking for, but it's certainly in the are of what you are after. IF that isn't the logic you are after, I think sample data and desired results would REALLY help.

Comment: @JNevill, thank you again. I think this could work! 
TableA looks like
 id timestamp   topic payload
 1 2023-06-23 22:58:49 5/3/75 25.4
 2 2023-06-23 22:58:47 10/3/100 100
 3 2023-06-23 22:58:36 5/2/200 25.38
 4 2023-06-23 22:58:23 5/2/100 24.9

Table B looks like
ID Timestamp   dailyEnergy status 
1 2023-06-23 23:02:29 51.28 Aus
2 2023-06-23 23:01:59 51.28 Aus
3 2023-06-23 23:01:29 51.28 Aus

How the heck could I format here?!?